# Get whole result when using J console

Tags: j

When using J console ijconsole I get only results up to some. For example,

```
ijconsole -js "a=.  3 3 5 6 " "echo 200 $ a" "exit''" 
3 3 5 6 3 3 5 6 3 3 5 6 3 3 5 6 3 3 5 6 3 3 5 6 3 3 5 6 3 3 5 6 3 3 5 6 3 3 5 6 3 3 5 6 3 3 5 6 3 3 5 6 3 3 5 6 3 3 5 6 3 3 5 6 3 3 5 6 3 3 5 6 3 3 5 6 3 3 5 6 3 3 5 6 3 3 5 6 3 3 5 6 3 3 5 6 3 3 5 6 3 3 5 6 3 3 5 6 3 3 5 6 3 3 5 6 3 3 5 6 3 3 5 6 3 3 5 6 ...
```

or

```
ijconsole -js "a=.  3 3 5 6 " "echo 2000 $ a" "exit''" 
3 3 5 6 3 3 5 6 3 3 5 6 3 3 5 6 3 3 5 6 3 3 5 6 3 3 5 6 3 3 5 6 3 3 5 6 3 3 5 6 3 3 5 6 3 3 5 6 3 3 5 6 3 3 5 6 3 3 5 6 3 3 5 6 3 3 5 6 3 3 5 6 3 3 5 6 3 3 5 6 3 3 5 6 3 3 5 6 3 3 5 6 3 3 5 6 3 3 5 6 3 3 5 6 3 3 5 6 3 3 5 6 3 3 5 6 3 3 5 6 3 3 5 6 3 3 5 6 ...
```

gives the same result. How to get whole result and not `...` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This option is controlled by the [global parameter](https://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/dx009.htm) `9!:37 y` "Output Control". Set the maximum line length (2nd number) to something appropriate to avoid the `...`:

```
9!:37 ] 0 2000 0 222
a =. 3 3 5 6
echo 2000 $ a


9!:37 ] 0 _ 0 222      NB. set maximum lines to infinity
```

Answer (score 1):

The ... at the end of the output line indicates it has been truncated.

See "Output Control" section at https://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Vocabulary/Foreigns#m9

9!:36'' NB. current settings
0!:37 [0 1000 0 1000 NB. displays longer lines and more lines

Answer (score 0):

Format the result to a string and use `stdout`.

`stdout ": 200 $ a`

Comment: stdout looks to have permit 5x as much output as echo, but it's still limited by default. Check `stdout 1e3$'a'`

Comment: @JulianFondren I can't hit the limit even with 30e3

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much. Indeed,

```
ijconsole -js '9!:37 ] 0 _ 0 222' "a=.3 3 5 6 " "echo 1000 $ a" "exit''"
```

works!

Comment: Since you are new to Stack exchange you may not know that by accepting one of the answers you not only reward the person who answered the question, but you also signal that the question has been answered which is very valuable for those who are looking for a similar answer. It is really nice to acknowledge the correct answer in the answers sections, but it is much harder for others to see that the question has been answered. BTW you asked a very good question. :-)